# Merging master into feature branch

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am moving our build pipeline from Jenkins to Bitbucket. In Jenkins, when we build a branch, we merge master into the branch to check for conflicts, and run unit tests after that, since the feature branch might be behind.

Bitbucket Pipeline clones only the specific branch: `git clone --branch="DEV-9-issue" --depth 50 https://x-token-auth:$REPOSITORY_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN@bitbucket.org/<team>/<repo>.git $BUILD_DIR`

**Question:** How can I get the master branch so I can merge it into this feature branch?

**Solutions I have come up with:**

1. Using an App Password, which can only be added to a personal account, not a team.
2. Adding an SSH key to my docker image.
3. Using OAuth which will require creating a script that gets an access token each time the build runs (access tokens expire after an hour).

Isn't there a better way?

**Pipeline:**

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git remote add ss https://<username>:<app_password>@bitbucket.org/<team>/<repo>.git
          - git merge --no-commit --no-ff ss/master
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set clone depth option to "full": Details: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_depth

**Example:**

```
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git merge --no-commit --no-ff origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a lot simpler than having to manually merge stuff.

> A special pipeline that only runs on pull requests initiated from
> within your repository. It merges the destination branch into your
> working branch before it runs. Pull requests from a forked repository
> don't trigger the pipeline. If the merge fails, the pipeline stops.
>
> > Pull request pipelines run in addition to any branch and default
> > pipelines that are defined, so if the definitions overlap you may get
> > 2 pipelines running at the same time.
>
> If you already have branches in your configuration, and you want them
> all to only run on pull requests, replace the keyword branches with
> pull-requests.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#pull-requests

instead of :

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - git remote add ss https://<username>:<app_password>@bitbucket.org/<team>/<repo>.git
          - git merge --no-commit --no-ff ss/master
          - ...your other steps
```

do:

```
pipelines:
  pull-request:
    '**':
      - step:
          script:
            - ... your other steps
```